# Uploading large password protected ZIP file over HTTP

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, vert.x

I have password protected zip file of 2GB. At client side,i am splitting file in chunks by setting fixed chunk size of 100MB,using apache HttpClient i am uploading each chunk by sending current chunk and total chunk with request
e.g `/upload/currentchunk/totalchunk` 
at server side , I am reading chunk by order and writing those chunk to file "Received.zip".

Everything works fine for simple zip file but for "password protected zip file" file is getting corrupted. what could be issue?

I have compared original file and file merged at server side both have same
1)size (number of bytes) and 2) size on disk (number of bytes)

when I open "Received.zip" in winRAR. CRC32 of file is showing 00000000.

Comment: i am sure they are in correct order

Comment: If you do a binary compare of the sent and the received files, do they differ?

Comment: both files are same,I have compared two files

Comment: How did you compare the files? Are they working on the client side?

Comment: Both files are not the same, otherwise you don't have a problem. You will have to post some code.

Comment: It was my silly mistake..... chunk were not in proper order